# Matplotlib: image.get_window_extent(renderer) produces all zeros

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am finding that the get_window_extent method for an image object gives all zeros.

For example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.array([[0.25, 0.75, 1.0, 0.75], [0.1, 0.65, 0.5, 0.4], \
    [0.6, 0.3, 0.0, 0.2], [0.7, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6]])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
im_obj = ax.imshow(im, extent = [0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 0.75], interpolation = 'nearest')
```

produces the following plot

[image]

Now I want to get the image size in display coordinates, so I do the following:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
renderer = fig.canvas.renderer
im_bbox = im_obj.get_window_extent(renderer)
```

The trouble is `print im_bbox` produces `Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 0.,  0.]])')`.  The method `.get_window_extent(renderer)` works fine with text, lines, and patches, so I was a bit surprised to see it does not work with images.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

In case it matters, I am using Matplotlib 1.3.0 with the TkAgg backend.

---

EDIT:

Here is a work around to get the image bounding box in display coordinates

```
im_ext = im_obj.get_extent()
im_pts = np.array([[im_ext[0], im_ext[2]], [im_ext[1], im_ext[3]]])
bbox = mpl.transforms.Bbox(im_pts)
fig.canvas.draw()
bbox = bbox.transformed(ax.transData)
```

Now `print bbox` produces `Bbox('array([[ 236.375,  148.2  ],\n       [ 433.975,  345.8  ]])')`.  I have also confirmed that these values are correct.  The following code:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
rect = Rectangle([bbox.x0, bbox.y0], \
    bbox.width, bbox.height, \
    linewidth = 8, color = [1,0,0], \
    fill = False)
fig.patches.append(rect)
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.savefig('wtf.png', dpi = mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'])
```

produces the following plot

[image: whew]

This workaround should be robust, but it isn't simple.  It took me a while to figure out that I had to do `fig.canvas.draw()` before I transformed the image bounding box from axes coordinates to display (pixel) coordinates.  Without `fig.canvas.draw()` the transformation is done incorrectly.  I guess matplotlib needs to draw everything first so it knows how to convert to display coordinates.

Thus, the original question remains.  Why does `im_obj.get_window_extent(renderer)` give a bounding box with all zeros?

Answer (score 5):

The reason that you get all zeros is that until you have rendered the artist (done by calling `draw()`) at least once, it has no way of knowing how big it is.  This is a consequence of matplotlib being lazy and not doing the work of rendering the artists until it *has* to.

Your workaround is correct and is essentially what mpl does internally for things like `tight_layout` and saving with a tight bounding box.

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me too after I figured out my workaround.  However, I tried putting a `fig.canvas.draw()` right before `renderer = fig.canvas.renderer`, yet it did not do anything.  The `im_obj.get_window_extent(renderer)` still produced all zeros.  I have updated my original post to reflect this.